# build-helper-maven-plugin report error sources is missing

Tags: maven-plugin, build-helper-maven-plugin

I try to use build-helper-maven-plugin 1.9 to add integration test folder, Pom shows below:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.9</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/integrate/java</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

the maven version is 3.2.2, when I run mvn build-helper:add-source, it throws errors below:

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source (default-cli) on project test: The parameters 'sources' for
goal org.codehaus.mojo:build-helper-maven-plugin:1.8:add-source are missing or invalid -> [Help 1]

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0):

Fix it in Eclipse with install APT M2E Connector, m2e Connector for build-helper-maven-plugin.

now the folder shows in Eclipse correctly.